# How to change the dragbar of an embedded video?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for myself with quite some videos, which I simply embed at my website since I'll be the only person to use it. Now I have a few different websites from which I use the videos (such as Youtube and DailyMotion) and different websites have different styles of their videos, things like the dragbar or the loading animation for example. I want to have all the videos look the same but I can't find anything about how to change things like the dragbar.
So my question is: Is it possible to change the dragbar, and if so, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I did some research myself but I simply could not find anything about it :/
Also I don't expect anybody to write the code for me. I just don't know where to start and I'd like know know where I should start, to give me some tips :)

Comment: Yeah... that's not likely to happen.  You would need to have an accessible API for each provider and develop the interface (presumably in javascript) to handle each video source.  You'll face hurdles like inconsistent feature sets (maybe one lets you skip ahead by 15 sec, one lets you skip arbitrary amounts, and one doesn't let you skip at all).  You might be better off instead normalizing the link to each video (thumbnail of video and a "play" indicator) and stuffing the embedded player into a modal.  It keeps your page looking consistent, but takes very minimal third party api integration.

Comment: What you're proposing might still be possible, though.  It would take a lot of work.  DailyMotion [has an API](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-api) and [so does YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).  If you can limit your videos to a defined set of providers and the providers all support pause, skipping to a particular spot, and embedding without the GUI, you might be able to pull it off.  You'll need to limit your list of providers and check each API for those three features.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respons (to Alon as well as to Joseph)!
I'll see what I can do with this; thanks again :)